# Architecture: How to implement status which affects several UI objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, architecture, switch-statement

I can only come up with solutions to the following problem which i find quite unsatisfying:

I want several UI elements to change their behaviour (mostly just dis/enable or change visibility) depending on a status (integer between 0-8) that i want to be able to modify from several places in my application.

Is there a more elegant way than implementing a huge switch/case block in the setter of my status property (implementing a strategy pattern doesn't really seem to be a better solution since i am just switching 'some' flags)? Maybe you can do some magic with databinding here? Currently i use a dedicated flag in my viewmodel for all the UI-object-properties that i need to change (which in turn are modified in the setter of the status-property...)

I guess some sort of conditional databinding would be the most elegant thing i can think of, but i would like to get some input if there are other viable ways to implement this.

Comment: What is your UI technology? WPF, MVC, Aspnet?

Comment: I am using WPF with MVVM (allthough i would change a winForms project as well if any of your suggestions are applicable.)

Comment: Use databinding? If you want more specific answer, ask specific question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a converter designed to convert your status (int) to wether or not the control is enabled (bool).

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
public class StatusToEnabledConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int status = (int)value;

        switch (status)
        {
            case 1: return true;
            case 2: return false;
            default: return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, you can bind the isEnabled of all controls you want to influence to your status code, converting it with that converter.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StatusToEnabledConverter x:Key="statusConvert"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding status, Converter={StaticResource statusConvert}}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

For visibility, you could do the exact same thing, using a StatusToVisibilityConverter and return Visibility.Visible, or Visibility.Collapsed.

...Or if you want to get technical and reuse the previous converter, you could design a boolToVisibilityConverter and chain the converter above to this new one.